# how to handle forgetPassword in android application while data fetching from magento procedures

Tags: android

The following link that I followed 
[android](https://www.mindstick.com/Articles/1673/sending-mail-without-user-interaction-in-android) works fine but if I am using **admin id** and **password** then it is no working.
I want send an email(random number) to customer emailId.
And can I send mail without using admin emilid password?

Comment: admin does't have gmail account. It has admin.xyz.com

Answer (score 1):

No you can not. Instead for the first time you can save email id of customer in shared preference and if user had forgotten the password then you can fetch this id from shared Preference and send a random number at this id.